# Re-generate all ComputedProperty fields

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'd like to add a ComputedProperty field to a Model of which there are a many existing entities in the datastore.

To query the existing entities on this new ComputedProperty, I need to generate the computed property first.

What is the most efficient way to trigger a compute and put the computed value back into the datastore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends how much data you have really. Here's a task queue solution, but it will eat away at your quota ...

```
class StampValue(webapp.RequestHandler):
    _task_url = '/tasks/stamp'
    _page_size = 100

    @classmethod
    def fire(cls, **params):
        taskqueue.add(url=cls._task_url, params=params)

    def get(self):
        self.fire()

    def post(self):
        key = self.request.get('key')
        if key:
            entities = MyModel.gql('WHERE __key__ >= :1 ORDER BY __key__ ASC', db.Key(key)).fetch(self._page_size+1)
        else:
            entities = MyModel.gql('ORDER BY __key__ ASC').fetch(self._page_size+1)

        key = None
        if len(entities) == self._page_size+1:
            key = str(entities[-1].key())
            self.fire(key=key)
            entities = entities[:self._page_size]

        for entity in entities:
            # update your field here
        db.put(entities)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how many entities you are talking about. Use [MapReduce](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/overview) or simply Remote API (launch a console and do it manually)